# org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: ... why it was?

Tags: hibernate, spring

Hi i am using Spring-Hibernate with `HibernateDaoSupport`, where my Dao was extends by `HibernateDaoSupport`. when i am getting the data from table the following error was raising, when i am submitting the data on same table it running successfuly.. can any one give your idea?

Error:

> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type setter of com.mypack.table.TblValues.minval; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type setter of com.mypack.table.TblValues.minval

Note: `minval` is the one of the column in table `TblValues`, and i assigning null value.

code in table pojo for getter & setter property:

```
@Column(name="minVal",nullable=true)
    public byte getMinVal() {
        return this.minVal;
    }
public void setMinVal(byte minVal) {
        this.minVal = minVal;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a `nullable` primitive type, that's a contradiction (in Java, at least).

If you want `minVal` to be nullable, you need to use the `Byte` java type, not `byte`.

Comment: i didnt take the byte datatype myself i used the Reverse Engineering in NetBeans it generates automatically

Comment: @Naresh: That may be the case, but it's what's causing your problem. That generated code will not work.